# Removing accents from 2 byte characters in ASCII string

Tags: perl

I am reading data from server which is returned as JSON and parsed using JSON::Parse. The JSON data includes accented characters such as é. These are encoded in the output strings as 2 byte characters such as \xc3\xa9. The rest of the string is standard 1 byte ASCII characters.

How can I remove the accents from these characters? I have tried all of the following methods without success:

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
use utf8;
use Text::Iconv;
use Encode qw(from_to);
use Text::Unidecode;

sub normalise_text {
  my $text = shift;
  my $decomposed = NFKD( $text );
  $decomposed =~ s/\p{NonspacingMark}//g;
  return $decomposed;
}

sub convert {
  my $converter = Text::Iconv->new("utf16", "utf8");
  return $converter->convert($_);
}

sub fromto {
  return from_to($_, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
}
```

These libraries tend to convert each character on a byte by byte basis which is no good. For the short term, I am doing the conversion as follows:

```
sub mine {
  my $text = $_;
  $text =~ s/\xc3\xa9/e/g;
  $text =~ s/\xc3\xa1/a/g;
  return $text;
}
```

There must be a better way! Any suggestions?

Comment: I did try unidecode without success but thanks for the idea. I have now fixed the problem another way (when parsing the JSON).

Comment: Looks like mojibake is happening somewhere. Is the JSON text you're getting already including those sequences?

Comment: If so, something along the line is taking UTF-8 encoded text and treating it like a single byte encoding and escaping the non-ascii bytes (incorrectly, since `\xXX` isn't a JSON escape sequence.)

Comment: If you're getting valid utf-8 encoded JSON, it's something you're doing and the question needs a [mcve] complete with sample JSON.